# Understanding Java Iterator

Tags: java, loops, iteration

If I run the following code, it will print out 3 times duplicate, but when I remove the if statement inside the while loop (just to see how many times it will iterate) it starts an infinite loop.

How does actually this `hasNext()` method working? I thought that will iterate only 5 times as I have 5 items in the list.

```
    public class ExerciseOne {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String []colors = {"MAGENTA","RED","WHITE","BLUE","CYAN"};
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String color : colors)
            list.add(color);
        String[] removeColors = {"RED","WHITE","BLUE"};
        List<String> removeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String color : removeColors)
            removeList.add(color);

        removeColors(list,removeList);
        System.out.printf("%n%nArrayList after calling removeColors:%n");
        for(String color : list)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s ",color);
        }
    }

    private static void removeColors(Collection<String> collection1, Collection<String> collection2)
    {
        Iterator<String> iterator = collection1.iterator();

            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                if(collection2.contains(iterator.next()))
                    System.out.println("duplicate");
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: `hasNext` does not move iterator cursor, `iterator.next()` moves it, so when you've removed condition you actually removed cursor change too

Comment: Yes of course, "Returns true if the iteration has more elements", but I cant understand when It reaches the end of the list why it continues the loop, I will try to find some other tutorial or documentation because that one from oracles' is not that clear for me

Comment: check answer of @leo its correct

Comment: @imoteb, it _doesn't_ reach the end of the list.  If you remove the `if` condition you never move the iterator forward at all, it's just stuck at the start of the list forever.

Comment: thank you @LouisWasserman and Lashane that was the thing that I could not understand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is pretty simple, actually

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    if(collection2.contains(iterator.next()))
       System.out.println("duplicate");
}
```

Imagine that the iterator is a pointer to an element of your list.

When you call `next()`, you're moving this pointer one step ahead.

If you don't move the pointer, `hasNext()` will always be true because you're still in the beginning of the list.

So you have to call the iterator's `next()` until there isn't any remaining element in the list.

Comment: Thank you , now I got it

Comment: @leo you say it is LIKE a pointer ("imagine"). But, is it a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the if statement, then it will go for an infinite loop since your `iterator.next()` is in the if condition. Actually `iterator.next()` is the api that moves the pointer, not the `hasNext()`. `hasNext()` just checks if there is any element in the collection. Since removal of the if statement is also removing the `hasNext` api, the pointer to the collection is not moving and `hasNext` is always returning true.

If you take out the `iterator.next()` from the if condition and move it above the if condition, then the loop will iterate for 5 times even after you remove the if statement.

```
Iterator<String> iterator = collection1.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
      String currentColor = iterator.next();
      if(collection2.contains(currentColor)){
         System.out.println("duplicate");
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erick for pointing that. That was my first answer ever in SO. I edited my answer based on your comment, although it has been explained properly in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Erick.

Answer (score 1):

```
The question why Iterator is important/introduced is simple:
consider following example:
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Anurag");
list.add("Soni");
list.add("MMM");
list.add("GKP");

for(string s : list){
  if(s.equals(" Anurag")
  s.remove();
  System.out.println(s);
}

This will throw an exception-`Concurrent Modification exception` as you are trying to alter the structure of the data structure List before the iteration is completed.

so you may use Iterator for the same purpose .
Iterator iterator = List.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
String current = iterator.next();
if(current=="Anurag"){
  iterator.remove();
}else{
System.out.println(current);
}

}
OUTPUT:  Soni
         MMM
         GKP
```